# Mis datos de foreach no cambian C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, foreach

Mis datos de mis foreach no cambian mantienen los mismos y despues de ingresar dos igual sale error en el index de los datos, si pudieran ayudarme, de antemano gracias

```
protected void btnLista_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EjemploConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Nombre,Apellido,Descripcion from Auditor " +
                     "inner join Zonas on Zonas.IdArea<>Auditor.IdArea " +
                     "order by NEWID()", conn))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        int cant = dt.Rows.Count;
        //string[] Nombre ;
        for (int j = 0; j < cant; j++) //Genera una seleccion de la cantidad del select de datos
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) //Los contabiliza 1 a 1
            {
                List<string> nombres = new List<string>(); //Selecciona el nombre y lo guarda para despues ingresarlo en la base de datos
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    nombres.Add(dr["Nombre"].ToString());
                    break;
                }
                List<string> apellido = new List<string>();//Selecciona el apellido y lo guarda para despues ingresarlo en la base de datos
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    apellido.Add(dr["Apellido"].ToString());
                    break;
                }
                List<string> descripcion = new List<string>();//Selecciona la zona y lo guarda para despues ingresarlo en la base de datos
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    descripcion.Add(dr["Descripcion"].ToString());
                    break;
                }
                string Sql = "insert into BBQ (Nombre,Apellido,Descripcion)" +
                    "Values (@Nom,@Ape,@Des)";
                SqlCommand cmt = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);
                cmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nom", nombres[i]);
                cmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ape", apellido[i]);
                cmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", descripcion[i]);
                conn.Open();
                cmt.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (i == 38)//La cantidad de los datos es muy elevada para la que debe de seleccionarse, y esto limita la cantidad que deben ingresarse
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Al momento de los foreach despues de ingresar una vez el dato no lo cambia y quitando los break hace un bucle en el mismo foreach, despues de ingresar dos datos iguales, realiza el siguiente error

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Parameter name: index'

Lo que requiero hacer con el codigo es una seleccion aleatoria para auditorias entre 39 zonas y 9 personas, el codigo realiza el random con la variable NEWID de Sql pero no me limita los datos me salen alrededor de 300 datos, lo traje a C# para poder limitarlo de una manera mas efectiva, los foreach me toma datos aleatorios de la tabla donde estan los nombres, los apellidos y las zonas, al momento de ingresar uno, mantiene el mismo dato en los tres y despues de ingresar dos datos iguales me manda el error ya antes puesto, intente varias soluciones por internet mas no me funcionaron, no soy un profesional en la programacion, soy un estudiante, y los break se que me mantienen el mismo dato, pero si los quito no salta el foreach y hace el bucle que el foreach debe realizar, gracias por tomar su tiempo para ayudarme

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta es bastante confusa.. de que datos hablas? a que tienen que cambiar? en que parte de tu codigo? te das cuenta que hay un break; adentro de tu for each, que hace que ejecute una sola vez no?

Comment: Separa tus funciones primero el select y luego insert.

Comment: Es una funcion para auditorias y seleccionar las zonas y las personas de una forma aleatoria, me hace el registro de aleatorio pero en el momento de los foreach me mantiene el mismo dato y si quito el break realiza el mismo bucle y no avanza del primer foreach, solo debe seleccionar tanto nombre, apellido y zona diferentes a los anteriores ya seleccionados

Comment: Primero lee lo que comenta @gbianchi,  ahora para leer datos en la ejecucion es declaras la coneccion  y abres, ejecutas el querie lees datos y cierras conexion. Intenta primero eso y agrega el error que te marca en el codigo, dentro de tu pregunta, no como un comentario, asi se entendera mejor el problema

Comment: Si comentas tu codigo con lo que hace cada parte, te vas a dar cuenta que no tiene mucho sentido.. Yo no entiendo que queres hacer. Ademas en ese codigo hay un solo for each... lo que hay son tambien dos for...

Comment: ¿Cómo que te mantiene el mismo dato? Como tienes break dentro de tus foreach, siempre tomará el nombre, apellido y descripción que se encuentren en la primera fila de tu conjunto de datos (dt) y te está insertando esos datos todo el tiempo. ¿Qué es lo que pretendes hacer? Está muy confusa tu pregunta.

Comment: Deberias de ir pensando en usar sqltransaction si quieres hacer diferentes querys dentro de la misma funcion/metodo.

Comment: Toda tu logica esta mal, por eso no te anda nada de lo que queres hacer. El foreach no randomiza nada, siempre recorre la lista de la misma forma. No se porque pensaste eso. Entonces guardar a una variable sola el resultado de hacer un foreach siempre guarda el ultimo valor. Si tu idea era randomizar una lista, podias hacerlo directamente en sql sin tener que hacer todo esto, asignando un guid a cada fila y ordenando por ese campo, y quedandote con las filas que querias. Entiendo que seas novato, pero esto es lo que llamamos un problema XY.. Estas usando la solucion equivocada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas son mis consideraciones:

- Los 2 `for` sobran.
- Simplemente con un foreach y tuplas hubieras resuelto

```csharp
var lista  = new List<(Nombre, Apellido,Descripcion)>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
     lista.Add((dr["Nombre"].ToString(), dr["Apellido"].ToString(), dr["Descripcion"].ToString()));
```

Según me imagino deseas guardar lo que genera una consulta a SQL. O sea, creo que esta es la idea que necesitas

```
    protected void btnLista_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EjemploConnectionString1"].ConnectionString))
        using(DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Nombre,Apellido,Descripcion from Auditor " +
               "inner join Zonas on Zonas.IdArea <> Auditor.IdArea " +
               "order by NEWID()", conn))
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into BBQ (Nombre,Apellido,Descripcion)" +
              "Values (@Nombre,@Apellido,@Descripcion)", conn))
        {
            //declaro la longitud de los datos a introducir
            int nombreLongitud = 35, apellidosLongitud  = 5, descLongitud = 50;
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 38) //La cantidad de los datos es muy elevada para la que debe de seleccionarse, y esto limita la cantidad que deben ingresarse
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            else{
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar, nombreLongitud, "Nombre"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Apellido", SqlDbType.NVarChar, apellidosLongitud, "Apellido"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Descripcion", SqlDbType.NVarChar, descLongitud, "Descripcion"));
                da.InsertCommand = cmd;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    dr.SetAdded();//.Fill establece por defecto las filas en Unchanged, por eso la convierto a Added

                da.Update(dt); //Realizo una inserción en masa
            }
        }
```

**SqlDataAdapter** permite y simplifica el hacer operaciones en BD sin necesidad de gastar esfuerzo en la construcción de los artefactos que interactúan con la misma

Comment: Buenas tardes, disculpa, ¿debo crear la variable para los nombrelongitud? y con los var me sale error en toda la Lista, no lee los nombres o asi parece

Comment: Era un ejemplo para que supiera que debia especificar la longitud de dichos parametros. Revisa la respuesta ahora

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho